# Hola, Quiero hacer un triger de auditoria donde me almacene el nombre de la tabla y campos que se haya modificado en SQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, trigger

es que quiero registrar auditoria de varias tablas, por lo tanto quiero tambien el nombre de la tabla para agregar dentro del triger, como debería de hacer?
gracias!

[image: el resultado de mi triger]

[image: las tablas creadas]

[image: el triger para insertar]

Comment: Tienes algo de código?

Comment: encontré un ejemplo de triger, es este:
CREATE TRIGGER trTableDatos_Insert
 ON tableDatos
AFTER INSERT
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Insert'
                FROM inserted;
     END;
GO

la tabla se llama datos y la tabla uditoriadatos, pero si quiero almacenar otra tabla en esa auditoria, como debería obtener el nombre de la tabla que estoy haciendo su CRUD?

Answer (score 0):

El escenario:

```
CREATE TABLE tableDatos
(id              INT
              IDENTITY(1, 1) 
              PRIMARY KEY, 
 columnaInt      INT, 
 columnaDateTime DATETIME, 
 columnaVarchar  VARCHAR(10), 
 columnaFloat    FLOAT
);
GO
 
CREATE TABLE auditoriaDatos
(id                INT, 
 columnaInt        INT, 
 columnaDateTime   DATETIME, 
 columnaVarchar    VARCHAR(10), 
 columnaFloat      FLOAT, 
 fechaInsertModify DATETIME, 
 typeMov           VARCHAR(25)
);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trTableDatos_Delete 
ON tableDatos
AFTER DELETE
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Delete'
                FROM deleted;
     END;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trTableDatos_Update 
ON tableDatos
AFTER UPDATE
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Before Update'
                FROM deleted;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'After Update'
                FROM inserted;
     END;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trTableDatos_Insert
 ON tableDatos
AFTER INSERT
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Insert'
                FROM inserted;
     END;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.tableDatos
(columnaInt, 
 columnaDateTime, 
 columnaVarchar, 
 columnaFloat
)
VALUES
(1, '20190130 15:45', 'Primera', 0.5);
GO
insert into dbo.tableDatos 
(
columnaInt, 
columnaDateTime,
columnaVarchar,
columnaFloat
)
values
(1,'20190130 15:45','Segunda',0.5),
(1,'20190130 15:45','Tercera',0.5),
(1,'20190130 15:45','Cuartaa',0.5),
(1,'20190130 15:45','Quinta',0.5),
(1,'20190130 15:45','Sexta',0.5);
Go
UPDATE dbo.tableDatos
  SET
      columnaFloat = 1, 
      columnaVarchar = 'Cuarta'
WHERE columnaVarchar = 'Cuartaa';
GO
```

Si quieres almacenar nombres de tablas en la auditoría, necesitas añadirle una columna.

```
Alter table dbo.auditoriaDatos 
Add tableName nvarchar(128);
```

Necesitas modificar los triggers existentes para añadir ese nombre de tabla al mismo.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trTableDatos_Delete 
ON tableDatos
AFTER DELETE
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Delete',
                       N'tableDatos'
                FROM deleted;
     END;
GO

ALTER TRIGGER trTableDatos_Update 
ON tableDatos
AFTER UPDATE
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Before Update',
                       N'tableDatos'
                FROM deleted;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'After Update',
                       N'tableDatos'
                FROM inserted;
     END;
GO
ALTER TRIGGER trTableDatos_Insert
 ON tableDatos
AFTER INSERT
AS
     BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO auditoriaDatos
                SELECT *, 
                       GETDATE(), 
                       'Insert',
                       N'tableDatos'
                FROM inserted;
     END;
GO
```

Actualizas los registros que tenías para que apunten a la tabla que ya disponías:

```
Update auditoriaDatos set tableName = N'tableDatos' 
where tableName is null;
```

Ahora creamos una tabla nueva.

```
Create table dbo.b (id int)
go
```

Un trigger para ella.

```
Create trigger dbo.b_insert on dbo.b
After insert
as
begin
    Insert into dbo.auditoriaDatos
    (id, 
    columnaInt,
    columnaDateTime, 
    columnaVarchar, 
    columnaFloat, 
    fechaInsertModify, 
    typeMov,
    tableName
    )
    Select inserted.id,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        GETDATE(),
        'Insert',
        N'b'
    
    From inserted ;
end
GO
```

Y como ves ya mencionamos la tabla, b en el trigger de su tabla.

```
insert into dbo.b (id)
values(1);
```

Y lo verificamos

```
select * from dbo.auditoriaDatos
```

[image: Resultado]

***Nota:*** Tienes que tener en cuenta, si la tablas que van a llenar esta tabla de auditoría, van a tener muchas operaciones, cuando la tabla alcance un tamaño de unos cuantos millones de filas, y vas a realizar alguna select sobre ella, convendría que la misma dispusiese de una clave primaria autogenerada.

[Auditoria de tabla con triggers](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/07/auditoria-de-tabla-con-triggers/)

[Identity](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/27/identity-o-autonumerico-verdades-y-mentiras/)

Comment: Graaaaciaaa!
Lo ejecutaré para poder realizar mi cambio en mi BD. @Javi fer2